# issue when trying to make a button get clicked when an hyperlink get clicked

Tags: jquery, html, button, hyperlink

I faced an issue when I try to make a button get clicked when an hyperlink get clicked i used this jquery code to do so :

```
$("a.mission").on("click", function() {

  $("button.boutonCode").trigger("click");
});
```

but when i click the hyperlink i get a strange effect , instead of doing the same action as the button, it does the action and goes to the previews page again which is not the case when i click the button :

Part of the HTML :

```
<button class="boutonCode effeckt-page-transition-button" data-effeckt-transition-in="scale-down-from-front" data-effeckt-transition-out="scale-down-to-behind" data-effeckt-transition-page="page-5" data-effeckt-needs-perspective="true">Code <i class="ion-arrow-right-c size-20"></i></button>


  <a href="" class="mission">
    <img src="images/mission.png" alt="" class="tooltipButton" data toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Code Tricks">
   </a>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://zerubeus.github.io/)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return false to link press event.

```
$("a.mission").click( function(e) {
 $("button.boutonCode").click();
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the a click event :

```
$("a.mission").click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   $("button.boutonCode").click();
});
```

Comment: try adding also what vishal kamal says..the return false; Or you should change the a href='' to href='#' because if not, the page gets reloaded.